# Should I split angular 2 module to providers module and components module?

Tags: angular, service

I have `LocalizationModule` that provides 3 services and 1 pipe that depends on one of the services which depends on second two (namely `I18nService`, `LocaleService`, `TranslateService`, `TranslatePipe`).

Now I want to provide custom providers for `I18nService` and `LocaleService`. So I import `LocalizationModule` in my `AppModule` and provide custom providers for specific services. To make it work in child components (lazy-loaded) I need to import `LocalizationModule` in the child components as well. And then my custom providers doesn't provide anymore for child components.

Ideally, I'd like these services to be singletones over whole app. Is it a good practice to split such modules into two modules, one for providers and the other for components? For example, `LocalizationModule` and `LocalizationProvidersModule`? Or is there some neater and finer way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `forRoot()` in `LocalizationModule` and provide global services only there and then import it in `AppModule` like

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [LocalizationModule.forRoot()]
  providesr: [myProvidersThatOverrideImportedProviders]
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root